WebSocket Connection Issue with ECS Container Behind API Gateway
We are currently facing an issue with establishing a WebSocket connection to a server hosted in an ECS container within a VPC.
Our cloud infrastructure is set up as follows:
UI → AWS API Gateway → Internal NLB → Internal ALB (via path-based routing) → ECS Containers
The problem is that we keep receiving a "400 Bad Request" error when attempting to establish the WebSocket connection through the API Gateway. We've tried different types of API Gateways but continue to face the same issue.
Interestingly, we were able to establish the WebSocket connection when we configured a public NLB to a public ECS container. This makes us suspect that we're missing some configuration detail in our current setup.
Tech Stack:
ECS Containers: Running NestJS with Socket.io version 4.7.5 (also tested with 3.1.2).
We would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance you could provide to help us resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance!
